# I get a recursion error when I click to fire a bullet

Tags: python

I am programming a target shooter game and have recently started using 'pygame.sprite'. I am currently programming the bullet function to shoot towards the cursor. I ideally want to use pygame.sprite for this to make use of the inbuilt collision system. I had an attempt at reusing code from another program I made and turning it into two functions, as shown below:

```
def bullet_maker():
 if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
   if event.button == 1:
     dx = event.pos[0] - (player_sprite.rect.x + player_sprite.rect.w // 2 )
     dy = event.pos[1] - player_sprite.rect.y
     direction = pygame.math.Vector2(dx, dy).normalize()
     bullet = {'x': player_sprite.rect.x + 42, 'y': player_sprite.rect.y, 'direction': direction}
     all_bullets.append(bullet)

def bullet_movement():
 for item in all_bullets:
   item['x'] += item['direction'][0] 
   item['y'] += item['direction'][1] 
   if 0 < item['x'] < 800 and 0 < item['y'] < 575:
           bullet_sprites.add(item)
```

My Bullet sprite class is shown below:

```
bullet_img = pygame.image.load('bullet.png')

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self, width, height):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, bullet_sprites) 
    self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
    self.image = bullet_img
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.center = (400,400)

bullet_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_bullets = []
```

Finally, my drawing function is shown below:

```
def refresh_window():
  window.blit(bgr, (0,0))
  player_sprites.draw(window)
  target_sprites.draw(window)
  for item in bullet_sprites:
    Bullet.image.draw(window)
  pygame.display.update()
```

It all runs well, but when I click the screen to fire a bullet, the game crashes and I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 123, in <module>
    bullet_movement()
  File "main.py", line 88, in bullet_movement
    bullet_sprites.add(item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pygame/sprite.py", line 366, in add
    self.add(*sprite)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pygame/sprite.py", line 366, in add
    self.add(*sprite)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pygame/sprite.py", line 366, in add
    self.add(*sprite)
  [Previous line repeated 330 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I assume it is a case of turning one of my functions into an iterative loop rather than a recursive one but I can't work out how to do this. Any help is massively appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a **global** declaration for *bullet_stripes*, at the beginning of *bullet_movement* function:

```
def bullet_movement():
 global bullet_sprites
 for item in all_bullets:
   item['x'] += item['direction'][0] 
   item['y'] += item['direction'][1] 
   if 0 < item['x'] < 800 and 0 < item['y'] < 575:
           bullet_sprites.add(item)
```